# In Android, should I receive fragment click events in fragment or activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am getting confused with regards to receiving, for example, a click event that is in my Fragment, should I pass this click event onto my activity or handle this in the fragment itself ?

I am also trying to thing of when I offer more than 1 fragment inside my activity, for example, a tablet version of an activity.

This also brings up another question I have, I have create a menu inside my activity and also inside my fragment where should I be checking the

```
 onOptionsItemSelected
```

inside the activity or fragment ?

I am very confused on where I should be handling click events and menus.

Comment: You should handle onClick events in the corresponding fragment. onOptionsItemSelected should go to your activity since it overrides activity method and menu is for your all fragments.

Comment: try to use eventbus [link] (http://square.github.io/otto/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle the click events both inside the fragment or from the activity itself, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Like suppose if the onClick event does some work that is locally handled by the fragment then you should handle it in the fragment itself but if the onClick event does some work which is related to other fragments(i.e other fragments included in the same activity) then you should probably use callback methods(listeners) to let the activity handle the click event.

For eg. suppose you are having two fragments namely- LogInFragment and LogOutFragment and you only show one fragment at a time inside the activity. Then let's say when the activity starts you are displaying the LogInFragment which has a button named Log In. When you click the button you can handle the onClick event to in the activity so that it can replace this fragment with the LogOutFragment.

Taking another scenario suppose when Log In button is clicked inside the LogInFragment you want to only change the text of the button to "Log Out" then this can be handled inside the fragment itself, so overall just think what you are trying to achieve and handle events accordingly.

2nd Part: onOptionsItemSelected() method is put inside the activity class and it handles the clicking of the menu items. Now if you are using another menu inside the fragment then this particular menu items click/selected events should be handled inside the fragment's class, fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks, very well explained. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

If the fragment that have the menu, appears in all the cases. the tablet and the phone. then you only need option menu in your fragment the Activity option menu will never appear.

In all cases add the following to your fragment class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Handle the fragment menu onOptionsItemSelected in the fragment itself and the activity menu onOptionsItemSelected in the activity. that's the best practice why should the Activity handles a feature that is not always exists. right? same thing for the click event.

If you need the activity to handle those events you can get it from inside your fragment as follow:

```
ActivityClassName activity = getActivity();
```

Even to set some value for the activity. do it in fragment. That's only an opinion. but Believe it's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there isn't an answer to that question that vaguely. Your fragment or specifically the views in your fragment get click events. You should typically handle them inside the click events. If they need to tell the Activity something then you need a method for facilitating the communications between the fragment and the activity, if you don't you don't. You can have fragments with their own menu items.

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
...
}
```

I've done it both ways at different times for specific purposes. Sometimes your Fragment is like a special control interface for part of your Activity and sometimes it's doing it's own thing. There is one one answer for all those things because there's no one program.

There's no one size fits all answer. But, generally you should handle the click events in the objects that are clicked, unless what they do is just tell some other object somethings, then they should do that.

If you want a more specific answer, give a more specific question.